# openpyxl _external_links too slow

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, openpyxl

I need to read a excel and get the external_books the excel used(for there is INDEX or VLOOKUP func used in the excel)

I choose openpyxl,the openpyxl.WorkBook._external_links api can do it well，but the speed is too slow（my excel is 600KB），about 27s

here is my code：

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(self.parent_path, name), use_iterators=False, data_only=True)
external_links = wb._external_links
```

Is there a way too speed up?

or other python excel lib to use?(I searched apis in xlrd,but found no same api to get the external_books)

Comment: To be clear: `wb._external_links` is not an API. The aim is simply to preserve existing external links when editing files with openpyxl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "read_only=True" option it should reduce time.